# How to slice based on index without copy/reset_index operations?

Tags: python, pandas

Take a boolean filter operation like this which returns a copy of the resulting data set:

```
df[(df.age > 20) & (df.age < 30)].
```

Now From the resulting set I want to choose a random slice based on the index. So for eg. I might want 10th, 14th and 17th rows.

But I can't say

```
df[(df.age > 20) & (df.age < 30) & df.index.isin([10, 14, 17])]
```

because the filtered index will be different. We can do this in 3 statements easily like this:

```
a = df[(df.age > 20) & (df.age < 30)]. 
a = a.reset_index()
result = a.index.isin([10, 14, 17])
```

That is a huge copy operation on potentially the whole data set (million rows), and then a reset operation.

I'd like to do this in one step without the copy operation. Any comments/insights appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One improvement on this is to use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html), which grabs only the rows in the specified *integer* positions:

```
a = df[(df.age > 20) & (df.age < 30)]
a.iloc[10, 14, 17]
```

*Note: this will throw an `IndexError` if `a` does not have 18 rows.*

See the [indexing section of the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html).

Comment: irow is cool. I hope it is an optimized lookup. I am starting to think my current requirement might not be supported in pandas. Although I suspect it is not too hard to modify to get this, I might be mistaken. The reason is because of the notation df[(df.age > 20) & (df.age < 30)][9:10] will fetch the 10th element exactly. So I suspect a lot of infrastructure to do this call is already in place.

Comment: @jason I don't *think* you can do that kind of "lazy" lookup, but I could be wrong.

Comment: `irow[]` is not available anymore for pandas versions older v0.19. Use `iloc[]` instead.

Comment: @normanius iloc didn't exist in early 2013 :) (it wasn't until 0.11! http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#selection-choices) - I really need to go through my old answers with a script to find all the deprecated functions/usage

Answer (score 0):

Just use `.ix`:

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4))

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    0   1   2   3
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19
```

Here I index the data frame where values of the first column are less than 12 and then use `.ix` to take the resulting 0th and 2nd rows:

```
In [3]: df[df[0] <12].ix[[0,2]]
Out[3]:
   0  1   2   3
0  0  1   2   3
2  8  9  10  11
```

**UPDATE:**

Ok, what about boolean indexing the index and then passing that to `.ix`?

```
In [1]: (df[0] < 12) | (df[0] > 12)
Out[1]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: 0
```

Index the df.index using the above boolean series:

```
In [2]: df.index[(df[0] < 12) | (df[0] > 12)]
Out[2]: Int64Index([0, 1, 2, 4], dtype=int64)
```

Now, use the above in `df.ix[]`. Here, passing a 3 pulls back the originally indexed 4th row:

```
In [3]: df.ix[df.index[(df[0] < 12) | (df[0] > 12)][3]]
Out[3]:
0    16
1    17
2    18
3    19
Name: 4
```

Comment: That would bring out based on existing index values, not the filtered index values. In your example, try df[df[0] > 8].ix[0,1], it will return NaN, although we have two rows in the result and we should be able to access them using .ix[0,1]. This is why the reset_index step is necessary.

Comment: ahh, duh, that was hasty of me.  I've edited my response with a possibly convoluted followup...

Comment: This certainly seems to get the job done. I am wondering if it has the lazy property, meaning: I wonder if df.index step is similar to df.reset_index() which would run through the entire list once which would defeat the purpose. I am thinking of timing it to see if this is the case or if it is infact lazy as required.

Comment: It is not lazy like I suspected. On a 500K row matrix this operation took 1.17 seconds. (2.4ghz/core2). I suspect this way of accessing things is not supported by pandas at this point. This is one reason where environments like Haskell which take laziness very seriously are at an advantage.

Comment: Thanks for following up on that. Do you know if it's faster than the reset_index method?

Comment: I must correct the previous report, it was 50 million rows and not 500K like I said. But the conclusion remains. As to which one is faster, it seems df.index[] method is about 10 times faster than df.reset_index().